# BTC on Mycelium to Bitcoin Gold?

Tags: mycelium-wallet, bitcoin-gold

I have some BTC on my Mycelium (Android) wallet and I was wondering if it's possible to now access (hopefully) my Bitcoin Gold. It seems I can't get the normal private keys off of Mycelium, but I have my 12 word seed at hand.

Are there any wallets compatible with Mycelium's 12 word seed that will allow my to access the Bitcoin Gold?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use your seed! It will compromise your whole wallet. 
Export your current account's private key in settings->export on an account.
Before using this private key anywhere. Add a new account and send your Bitcoin to this new account in Mycelium. Now you can use the exported private key to claim your Bitcoin gold. 
However where you can do this is still unknown to me. Apparently Bitcoin Gold will provide guides for all wallets including Mycelium.